# PHP: How do I create variables from a given array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create separate variables from the key of an array where variable is the key and the content is the value of that key in the array

Comment: If you want to use `extract` for this, be aware that the default mode is `EXTR_OVERWRITE` which poses the potential security risk of overwriting important existing variables. It is safer to use `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` or not to use `extract` at all

Comment: @Gordon: thanks for the warning. i am just looking for a solution for a local migration script :D

Comment: (deleted a series of off-topic comments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`extract($array);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

---

#### Example

```
<?php

$array = array('a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'def');

extract($array);

var_dump($a, $b);

// string(3) "abc"
// string(3) "def"
```

[See it](http://codepad.org/OzY4HcQ3).

Comment: +1 for being the first to supply a working solution along with an example.

Answer (score 6):

using this way
      $data=array();

```
  $data["value1"]=3;

  $data["value2"]=4;



  $three = $data["value1"];

  $four = $data["value2"];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function for this.

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);
```

which will give:

```
$color = 'blue'
$size = 'medium'
$shape = 'sphere'
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
 extract($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP's [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function will do exactly that.